# AMD Ryzen 5 2400G with Radeon Vega Graphics not recognized in HIP (linux)

Tags: drivers

My machine is an AMD Ryzen 5 2400G with Radeon Vega Graphics.

```
$ glxinfo -B | grep -i "OpenGL"

OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Vega 11 Graphics (raven, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.49, 6.2.9-arch1-1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

In Blender Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices > HIP, I see:

```
No compatible GPUs found for Cycles
Requires AMD GPU with Vega or RDNA architecture.
and AMD driver version 22.10 or newer
```

Can I get blender (under ArchLinux) to recognize the graphics card (Radeon Vega Graphics). Any tips would be appreciated.